# xml with nested siblings to data frame in R

Tags: xml, r, xpath, xml-parsing, dataframe

I am new to parsing XML in R. I am trying to parse XML into a workable data frame. I have tried some XPath functions from the XML package but cannot seem to arrive at the correct answer.

**Here is my XML:**

```
<ResidentialProperty>
    <Listing>
      <StreetAddress>
        <StreetNumber>11111</StreetNumber>
        <StreetName>111th</StreetName>
        <StreetSuffix>Avenue Ct</StreetSuffix>
        <StateOrProvince>WA</StateOrProvince>
      </StreetAddress>
      <MLSInformation>
        <ListingStatus Status="Active"/>
        <StatusChangeDate>2015-07-05T23:48:53.410</StatusChangeDate>
      </MLSInformation>
      <GeographicData>
        <Latitude>11.111111</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-111.111111</Longitude>
        <County>Pierce</County>
      </GeographicData>
      <SchoolData>
        <SchoolDistrict>Puyallup</SchoolDistrict>
      </SchoolData>
      <View>Territorial</View>
    </Listing>
    <YearBuilt>1997</YearBuilt>
    <InteriorFeatures>Bath Off Master,Dbl Pane/Storm Windw</InteriorFeatures>
    <Occupant>
      <Name>Vacant</Name>
    </Occupant>
    <WaterFront/>
    <Roof>Composition</Roof>
    <Exterior>Brick,Cement Planked,Wood,Wood Products</
</ResidentialProperty>
```

When I run:

```
ResidentialProperty <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//ResidentialProperty"))
```

The values of the child nodes within the  parent node is compressed to:

```
11111111thAvenue CtWA2015-07-05T23:48:53.41011.111111-111.111111PiercePuyallupTerritorial
```

If I move down one node to , the same thing happens:

```
11111111thAvenue CtWA
```

The values of the child nodes are all pasted together.

I also tried a brute force method which worked somewhat:

```
StreetAddress <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//StreetAddress"))
MLSInformation <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//MLSInformation"))
GeographicData <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//GeographicData"))
SchoolData <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//SchoolData"))
YearBuilt <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//YearBuilt"))
InteriorFeatures <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//InteriorFeatures"))
Occupant <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//Occupant"))
Roof <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//Roof"))
Exterior <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//Exterior"))
df <- cbind(StreetAddress, MLSInformation, GeographicData, SchoolData, YearBuilt, InteriorFeatures, Occupant, Roof, Exterior)
```

but some of the column names were not as expected:

```
> colnames(df)
 [1] "StreetNumber"     "StreetName"       "StreetSuffix"     "StateOrProvince"  "ListingStatus"   
 [6] "StatusChangeDate" "Latitude"         "Longitude"        "County"           "SchoolDistrict"  
[11] "text"             "text"             "Name"             "text"             "text"
```

`colnames[11,12,14,15]` should be `"YearBuilt", "InteriorFeatures", "Roof", and "Exterior"` respectively. (Side note - why does this happen?)

I am trying to find a way to sort each atomic value into an appropriate column of a data frame with the column names being the names of the nodes, even within nested children nodes. Also, my data may change over time, so I'm looking for a dynamic function to conform to the data, producing expected results if possible.

I imagine this is a somewhat common XML schema (with layers of nested children) so I am surprised to not find much info on the topic, though I may simply using the wrong jargon in my searches. It my guess that there is a simple answer. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering `xml` holds your example string, here's another strategy for Residential Properties with a varying number of items:

```
library(XML)
library(plyr) 
# xml <- '<ResidentialProperty>........'
doc <- xmlParse(xml, asText =  TRUE)
df <- do.call(rbind.fill, lapply(doc['//ResidentialProperty'], function(x) { 
  names <- xpathSApply(x, './/.', xmlName) 
  names <- names[which(names == "text") - 1]
  values <- xpathSApply(x, ".//text()", xmlValue)
  return(as.data.frame(t(setNames(values, names)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}))
df
#   StreetNumber StreetName StreetSuffix StateOrProvince        StatusChangeDate  Latitude   Longitude County SchoolDistrict        View YearBuilt                     InteriorFeatures   Name        Roof                                Exterior
# 1        11111      111th    Avenue Ct              WA 2015-07-05T23:48:53.410 11.111111 -111.111111 Pierce       Puyallup Territorial      1997 Bath Off Master,Dbl Pane/Storm Windw Vacant Composition Brick,Cement Planked,Wood,Wood Products
```

Comment: Luke you are a scholar and a gentleman. Works like a charm! Thank you it is much appreciated.  I upvoted your answer but I dont have the StackOverflow reputation for other to see it.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helps you, you can check it and mark the problem as solved.