# Nested XML into R dataframe

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to make the solution found here [xml with nested siblings to data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255107/xml-with-nested-siblings-to-data-frame-in-r)  work where there are repeated nests (I'm not an html person- so not sure if that is the right term)
The code referenced above is returning the first cycle, but I need to import all of the cycles.

The data look like this:

```
 <Record>
<LastName>REDACTED</LastName>
<FirstName>REDACTED</FirstName>
<DOB>REDACTED</DOB>
<Rapsheet>
  <Header>
    <DateOfBirth>REDACTED</DateOfBirth>
    <SID>REDACTED</SID>
    <Summary>
      <DateOfLastArrest>
        10/01/2012
      </DateOfLastArrest>
      <AgeOfOffender>21</AgeOfOffender>
      <FailuresToAppear>0</FailuresToAppear>
      <ViolationOfCourtOrdersOrConditions>
        0
      </ViolationOfCourtOrdersOrConditions>
      <FelonyArrestsConvictions>
        0/0
      </FelonyArrestsConvictions>
      <MisdemeanorArrestsConvictions>
        0/0
      </MisdemeanorArrestsConvictions>
      <UnknownOffenseLevelArrestsConvictions>
        1/0
      </UnknownOffenseLevelArrestsConvictions>
      <AssaultOnOfficerCharges>
        0
      </AssaultOnOfficerCharges>
      <DeadlyWeaponRelatedCharges>
        0
      </DeadlyWeaponRelatedCharges>
      <EscapeCharges>
        0
      </EscapeCharges>
      <ViolationOfProbationParoleCharges>
        0/0
      </ViolationOfProbationParoleCharges>
    </Summary>
  </Header>
  <Title>VERMONT CRIMINAL HISTORY</Title>
  <Identification>
    <VermontStateID>REDACTED</VermontStateID>
    <DateOfBirth>REDACTED</DateOfBirth>
    <PlaceOfBirthCity></PlaceOfBirthCity>
    <PlaceOfBirthStateOrCountry></PlaceOfBirthStateOrCountry>
    <Sex>F</Sex>
    <Race>W</Race>
    <Ethnicity>
    </Ethnicity>
    <USCitizen></USCitizen>
    <Height>503</Height>
    <Weight>180</Weight>
    <EyeColor>GRN</EyeColor>
    <HairColor>BLN</HairColor>
    <ScarsMarksTattoos>
      <SMTCode>TATTOO</SMTCode>
      <SMTDescription>ARABIC TATOO ON ARM</SMTDescription>
    </ScarsMarksTattoos>
    <ScarsMarksTattoos>
      <SMTCode>TATTOO</SMTCode>
      <SMTDescription>NOSE RING LIP RINGS</SMTDescription>
    </ScarsMarksTattoos>
    <PrintsNCIC></PrintsNCIC>
    <HenryUp></HenryUp>
    <HenryLow></HenryLow>
    <PhotoAvailable></PhotoAvailable>
    <Address>
      <Street>REDACTED</Street>
      <City>WINOOSKI</City>
      <State>VT</State>
      <Zip>05404</Zip>
    </Address>
  </Identification>
  <CriminalHistory>
    <Cycle>
      <CycleNumber>1</CycleNumber>
      <TrackingNumber>1709462</TrackingNumber>
        <Arrest>
          <DateOfArrest>10/01/2012 </DateOfArrest>
          <ArrestAgency>WINOOSKI PD VT0040400</ArrestAgency>
          <ArrestAgencyCaseNumber>12WS04470</ArrestAgencyCaseNumber>
          <Fingerprint>NO</Fingerprint>
          <Charge>
            <ChargeNumber>01</ChargeNumber>
            <ChargeDescription></ChargeDescription>
            <Statute></Statute>
            <Severity></Severity>
          </Charge>
        </Arrest>
        <Arraignment>
          <ArraignmentDate>04/18/2014</ArraignmentDate>
          <ArraignmentAgency>CHITTENDEN CO. DISTRICT COURT</ArraignmentAgency>
          <DocketNumber>REDACTED</DocketNumber>
          <Charge>
            <ChargeNumber>01</ChargeNumber>
            <ChargeDescription>ASSAULT-AGG DOMESTIC-1ST DEG WITH WEAPON</ChargeDescription>
            <Statute>13V1043A2</Statute>
            <Severity>FELONY</Severity>
          </Charge>
        </Arraignment>
        <CourtDisposition>
            <ChargeNumber>01</ChargeNumber>
            <Convicted>NO</Convicted>
            <Felony>NO</Felony>
            <ChargeDescription>ASSAULT-AGG DOMESTIC-1ST DEG WITH WEAPON</ChargeDescription>
            <Statute>13V1043A2</Statute>
            <Disposition>
              06/09/2014 CASE DISMISSED
            </Disposition>
        </CourtDisposition>
    </Cycle>
    <Cycle>
      <CycleNumber>2</CycleNumber>
      <TrackingNumber>1685833</TrackingNumber>
        <Arrest>
          <DateOfArrest>09/30/2012 </DateOfArrest>
          <ArrestAgency>WINOOSKI PD VT0040400</ArrestAgency>
          <ArrestAgencyCaseNumber>12WS004770</ArrestAgencyCaseNumber>
          <Fingerprint>NO</Fingerprint>
        </Arrest>
        <Arraignment>
          <ArraignmentDate>10/01/2012</ArraignmentDate>
          <ArraignmentAgency>CHITTENDEN CO. DISTRICT COURT</ArraignmentAgency>
          <DocketNumber>REDACTED</DocketNumber>
          <Charge>
            <ChargeNumber>01</ChargeNumber>
            <ChargeDescription>ASSAULT-AGG DOMESTIC-1ST DEG WITH WEAPON</ChargeDescription>
            <Statute>13V1043A2</Statute>
            <Severity>FELONY</Severity>
          </Charge>
        </Arraignment>
        <CourtDisposition>
            <ChargeNumber>01</ChargeNumber>
            <Convicted>NO</Convicted>
            <Felony>NO</Felony>
            <ChargeDescription>ASSAULT-AGG DOMESTIC-1ST DEG WITH WEAPON</ChargeDescription>
            <Statute>13V1043A2</Statute>
            <Disposition>
              12/02/2013 CASE DISMISSED
            </Disposition>
        </CourtDisposition>
    </Cycle>
  </CriminalHistory>
</Rapsheet>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Please don't expect people to just write all of your code for you with no attempts. (Because XML is flexible enough to *not* be simply columnar- or row-oriented data, there is no generic solution to the task.)

Comment: Before I found the link above- I had tried pretty much everything that poster had tried.  I don't understand well enough what the solution is doing to be able to modify it to meet my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider multiple calls to `xmlToDataframe` from `XML` package where you iterate through the length of *Cycle* node. Using `lapply` you can create a list of dataframes and with `plyr` package's `rbind.fill()` you can fill non-existent rows prior to row binding which is needed for any missing nodes such as the first *Charge* in second *Cycle*.

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)

doc <- xmlParse("path/To/XML.xml")    
cyclelen <- length(xpathSApply(doc, "//Cycle"))

dfList <- lapply(seq(cyclelen), function(i) {

  identification <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//Cycle[",i,"]/../../Identification")))
  names(identification) <- paste0("Identification.", names(identification))

  cycle <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//Cycle[",i,"]")))
  names(cycle) <- paste0("Cycle.", names(cycle))

  arrest <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//Cycle[",i,"]/Arrest")))
  names(arrest) <- paste0("Arrest.", names(arrest))

  arraign <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//Cycle[",i,"]/Arraignment")))
  names(arraign) <- paste0("Arraignment.", names(arraign))

  court <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//Cycle[",i,"]/CourtDisposition")))
  names(court) <- paste0("CourtDisposition.", names(court))

  cbind(identification, cycle, arrest, arraign, court)  

})

df <- rbind.fill(dfList)
```

Alternatively, the DRY-er version:

```
dfList2 <- lapply(seq(cyclelen), function(i) {

  do.call(cbind,
      lapply(c("Identification", "Cycle", "Arrest", "Arraignment", "CourtDisposition"), function(n){ 
        if (n=="Identification") {
          df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//Cycle[",i,"]/../../", n)))
        } else if (n=="Cycle") {
          df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//Cycle[",i,"]")))
        } else {
          df <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes = getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//Cycle[",i,"]/", n)))
        }
        names(df) <- paste0(n, ".", names(df))
        return(df)
       })
    )
})

df2 <- rbind.fill(dfList2)

all.equal(df, df2)
# TRUE
```

Do note: this approach create fields for *Cycle.Arrest*, *Cycle.Arraignment*, and *Cycle.Disposition* with all children node text concatenated but they are separated in individual columns anyway, so simply remove these three.

Output *(not all fields shown below)*

[image: Dataframe Output]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This was useful in getting to the cycles, but I then have to merge the cycles with some of the information in the . Identification Block. People have varying number of cycles, but only one Identification header.  There nothing in the cycle block to merge the cycle  df to the identification block,and the binds only work for equal rows, which I won't have.

Comment: sorry- in the Record block- I need to attach the name/dob to the cycles

Comment: See update. Simply extend to go up two node levels from current *Cycle* for *Identification* element.

Comment: Thank you- this has me on the right track for what I need to do.